# Phonegap/ Jquery Mobile Android App If Issue

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm having issues with a fairly basic If statement that I'm using to trigger a music playing sequence.  It's for an automated preview button.  Basically Its a pretty average preview - t the user clicks a button - the preview plays - and the button image switches to a pause icon , click again and the track will stop playing and image will switch back.

I've currently got the following script -

```
var playingTwo=false;
var playthis=null;

function previewThis(preview){
playthis = "/android_asset/www/" +"Paradise"+".mp3"
prevMedia= new Media(playthis, stopAudio, null);
playPrev();
}




function playPrev() {
if (!playingTwo) {
    prevMedia.play();
            $('.playBtnPrev').removeClass('sel')
    playVarTwo(); 

} else {
    prevMedia.stop();
            $('.playBtnPrev').addClass('sel')
    pauseVarTwo();              
}
}



function playVarTwo(){setTimeout( function() {

    playingTwo = true; 
}, 1000 );}


function pauseVarTwo(){setTimeout( function() {
playingTwo = false; 

}, 1000 );

}


  $('.playBtnPrev').live('tap',function(event) {previewThis();});
```

Basically the previewThis() script will eventually have the track name passed to it, it sets up the media location and triggers the playPrev() script - the play button detects whether or not its already playing - if not it plays - if its already playing it pauses and switches the images according - all fairly straightforward.

Initially I wrapped all the state functions in each If statement - although this worked fine in a browser - on mobile the If statement ran both state - so it would stop and start the track with a second gap.  So I split the state change into a set timeout function to make the if complete before the state changed - but still no joy, now it plays the track twice(overlapping), so its driving me insane!

Can anyone offer any advice please?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I include your code in a existing jquerymobile mine, and after comment some function like the part of instancing a Media object...

I see an error:

"playingTwo is not defined"

I think that you must set var playingTwo; before the function previewThis.

Let me know if this solve the problem.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks guys - it is actually there - i just missed it in the example above - i'll add now!

Answer (score 0):

as @Mariano wrote, I would suggest adding at the top of your file:

```
 var playingTwo = false;
```

since it's probably not assigned (nor created) when you are already checking for it's value.

Hope this helps!